# Rails 3 - link_to assign multiple classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I have a loop that links to every item in a collection:

```
<% current_user.projects.all.each do |p| %>
    <%= link_to p.name, project_path(p), :class => current_class?(project_path(p)), :id => p.theme %>
  <% end %>
```

Right now, I'm assigning a class for the anchor in addition to an id so I can apply some CSS. Really though, it would make more sense for me to have this as a double classed anchor. Is there a way to assign two classes to the same object with the link_to helper?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just separate them by spaces, as you would in ordinary HTML.

```
<%= link_to p.name, project_path(p), :class => "class1 class2 class3", :id => p.theme %>
```

You can generate the string however you want. If you have the classes you want as an array you could use `some_classes.join(" ")` to combine them.

Comment: actually, an array works too ... 
<%= link_to 'Home', '/', class: ['btn','btn-info','btn-large'] %> will generate
<a href="/" class="btn btn-info btn-large">Home</a>

Comment: Also: `<%= link_to p.name, project_path(p), :class => [:class1, :class2 :class3], :id => p.theme %>`

Comment: @titibouboul confirming this works at least from Rails 4: https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/tag_option